# What's the difference between the php7.0-sqlite and php-sqlite3 packages?

Tags: php

When you use apt-get, what's the difference between the php7.0-sqlite package and the php-sqlite3 package?

I'm trying to get a php PDO package

Comment: There is [no `php7.0-sqlite` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.0-sqlite).

Comment: I probably got it mixed up with an older version, thank you for the help again

Comment: Fixed it ^^^^^^ I meant the Php7.0- and the Php- packages

Answer (score 15):

`php7.0-sqlite3` is the package that provides the PHP plugins for SQLite3 Database support.

`php-sqlite3` is a metapackage that pulls in `php7.0-sqlite3` (in Xenial).  Part of the migration was that it is easier to just define a dependency on `php-sqlite3` or similar so if we ever go to `php7.1` or such, and a package just depends on `php-sqlite3` it automatically pulls in the correct version.  This also makes it easier on setup scripts and users to just install `php-sqlite3` instead of having to memorize what PHP numeric version is in use (or worse, hardcode the version to use).